Does the CC license of Stack Overflow content mean that the OpenAI model will also have to be CC licensed?
I don't see the point of the license if derivative works are not licensed in a similar way.
I don't think OpenAI will license their model like this, so what recourse do Stack Overflow users have?

@GinoMempin That does not address the question. OpenAI (or any LLM answer) has to do with the output of generative AI tools. The model involves training the LLM. The answer to both questions is different.

Related over on Law.SE: Answer to: Is it illegal for a firm to train an AI model on a CC BY-SA 4.0 corpus and make a commercial use of it without distributing the model under CC BY-SA?

For what it's worth, I think it does. Without the training material, OpenAI would just have a bunch of computers and an algorithm. That means the content is their main resource. Maybe CC could have been worded better to avoid that when it was created. Neuronal networks were already known when the CC was written. I wonder if anyone discussed it back then.

In the United States, there is ongoing litigation regarding using copyrighted materials for training models. Until those cases are resolved, there's no definitive answer. It's worth acknowledging that text and data mining is generally considered fair use. The Creative Commons has also written about the training of models being fair use. Although there are no clear-cut lines regarding fair use, the four factors must be considered case-by-case.
If training is fair use, then copyright laws and licenses based on copyright would not be enforceable. It is unclear if treating a license as a contract (common in open-source licenses, including Creative Commons licenses) would be enforceable. This would be a question that would need to be answered. It may be addressed in some of the ongoing litigation.
If the training is not considered fair use and the resultant model is considered a derivative work, then the licenses for all of the training material would need to be considered when selecting a license for the model.
There is also some proposed litigation in the US that requires disclosing information about what content was used to train a model. However, this has not progressed very far in the legislative process and may never come to fruition.
Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with laws and litigation outside the US to answer how other countries may view these questions.

Fair use seems a stretch for so much content. Quoting one thing is fair use, quoting everything that exists maybe not so much.

@Alper What do you mean? Keep in mind that Stack Overflow and all SE Network sites are collections of millions of pieces of work. Each question and each answer is a separate work. However, the amount of work used is only one factor in fair use, and using an entire body doesn't necessarily prevent a claim of fair use.

Good answer. Fair use for example is only a legal concept in some countries although others may have somewhat similar limitations. In the end OpenAI might be liable for damages in one part of the world and not in another. The situation is simply without precedent and there is lots of money at stake on both sides. For example, content creators could for a long time trust to commercially exploit and benefit from their work exclusively. OpenAI could be seen as profiting (as in making money) from the work of others without compensating them sufficiently (or at all).

"text and data mining" is not the same as AI model training. When you create new content purely out of existing content, that isn't and never has been fair use in history.

@Mecki AI model training is text mining. Text mining is defined as "transforming unstructured text into structured data for analysis". Tokenization and vectorization of text clearly fits this definition. Note that the use of a model to create content is not training.

@ThomasOwens "transforming unstructured text into structured data for analysis" - But that's not what happens. The data is not just transformed for analysis, it is transformed into new derived data, and derived data is protected by copyright, not fair use. There is a difference between me taking your story and just transforming the text into something machine-parsable and then collecting statistics about that text, and me making up a new story based on the characters and the fictional world that your story has created. By your definition, compiled code would be fair use but it clearly isn't

@Mecki You are conflating the training of the model with the use of the model in generative AI. Using a trained model to generate output is not the training of the model itself. In the United States, AI-generated content cannot receive copyright protection. There are still open legal questions about the output of trained models infringing on copyright - I suspect someone will be liable, but it's unclear how much responsibility falls to the user of the model versus the provider of the tool.

@ThomasOwens You are ironing the fact that when you train an AI with data and then make the AI generate data, the generated data is derived data of the training data. So even if training itself is fair use, you then must not use the AI for anything but personal use. The moment you use it to generate new data that is not for personal use you are generating derived data from copyright protected data. And I never said that AI generated data can receive copyright, I said by generating data you violate the copyright of the people who created the training data, unless it's for personal use only

@ThomasOwens The copyright law clearly says that any work derived from your work is also protected by your copyright. And derived work is defined as: "A work based upon one or more preexisting works, such as a translation, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization, motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment, condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast, transformed, or adapted." So you may train your AI with my work but the moment your AI produces anything based upon my work, it's a derived work.

@Mecki I don't understand what the output has to do with anything. The only thing that I am interested is in the input data used to train the model and the model itself. You are right that the output created using a model will likely be a derivative work. However, this answer is only about consuming work protected by copyright to create a model and the status of a model, nothing to do with the output produced by a model. The model itself is not a derivative work. In fact, a model may not even be copyrightable in the first place.

@ThomasOwens The output is important as copyright is irrelevant as long as you produce no output. Copyright never forbids me to use data for anything. I can take any protected story, movie, music, software and do with it whatever I want on my computer at home, as long as there is no output that ever leaves my computer. Only when it leaves my computer I might have broken someone's copyright. Copyright is all about distribution, you cannot break copyright without distributing anything.
